# Angular 4 comma not working on tablet android keyboard

Tags: android, angular, google-chrome, gboard

In our Angular app when browsing on a tablet one of our number input fields I cannot use comma when typing. I can use the dot, +, numbers but I can't input comma and I cant figure out why.

[image]

As you can see, when I tap on input field "Vrijednost" (croatian for 'value'), google keyboard GBoard opens up. I can type in dots (as seen in picture), but I can't use commas.

I tried doing this on desktop using Chrome browser and I can type in commas using phyisical keyboard, I even tried with Windows on-screen keyboard and it also works. Any suggestions why it wouldn't work on tablet using GBoard?

Grid code in component.html:

```
                        <ng-template ngFor let-c [ngForOf]="grid.columns" let-y="index">
                        <td *ngIf="c.name == 'value' && typeId != 2"><input class="form-control" type="number"  min="0" step="1" inputmode="numeric"  pInputText [(ngModel)]="item[grid.columns[y].dataKey]" id="value1-{{i}}" name="value1-{{i}}" (keyup)="changeItem(item, $event, i)" [required]="item.remark != null ? true : false" [readonly]="typeID == 0 ? true : false" /></td>
                        <td *ngIf="c.name == 'value' && typeId == 2"><input class="form-control" type="text" pInputText [(ngModel)]="item[grid.columns[y].dataKey]" id="value1-{{i}}" name="value1-{{i}}" (keyup)="changeItem(item, $event, i)" [required]="item.remark != null ? true : false" /></td>
                        <td *ngIf="c.name == 'value2' && typeId == 4 "><input class="form-control" type="number"  min="0" step="1" inputmode="numeric"  pInputText [(ngModel)]="item[grid.columns[y].dataKey]" id="value2-{{i}}" name="value2-{{i}}" (keyup)="changeItem(item, $event, i)" [required]="item.value1 != null && typeId == 4 ? true : false" /></td>
                        <td *ngIf="c.name == 'value2' && typeId == 5 "><input class="form-control" type="number"  min="0" step="1" inputmode="numeric"  pInputText [(ngModel)]="item[grid.columns[y].dataKey]" id="value2-{{i}}" name="value2-{{i}}" (keyup)="changeItem(item, $event, i)" /></td>
                        <td *ngIf="c.name == 'value3' && typeId == 5 "><input class="form-control" type="number"  min="0" step="1" inputmode="numeric" pInputText [(ngModel)]="item[grid.columns[y].dataKey]" id="value3-{{i}}" name="value3-{{i}}" (keyup)="changeItem(item, $event, i)" /></td>
                        <td *ngIf="c.name == 'remark'"><input class="form-control" type="text" pInputText [(ngModel)]="item[grid.columns[y].dataKey]" id="remark-{{i}}" name="remark-{{i}}" (keyup)="changeItem(item, $event, i)" [readonly]="typeID == 0 ? true : false" /></td>
                        <td *ngIf="c.name != 'value' && c.name != 'value2' && c.name != 'value3' && c.name != 'remark'">{{item[grid.columns[y].dataKey]}}</td>
                    </ng-template>
```

Comment: Commas and dots are changing according to your locale : in Croatia it seems to be a dot. In the USA, it would be a comma. If you want to control it, consider using text fields.

Comment: I changed OS language to croatian and now both commas and dots are allowed, how so?

Comment: I don't know, I know it's about locales, but I don't know every locale ! But be careful, allowing both usually mean they have different meanings (for instance, dot is for separating hundreds for thousands, while comma is for decimals)

Comment: Thank you, the problem is now easier to understand. I'm gonna look into what data is saved when using either comma or dot.